# Using moment.js locales on ngx-bootstrap datepicker

Tags: datepicker, momentjs, ngx-bootstrap

ngx-bootstrap has a custom implementation for datepicker locales. 
As my project is already using moment.js locales, i'm wondering is it possible to use moment.js locales with ngx-bootstrap datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use both the follow way:

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <label>Date</label>
            <input [(ngModel)]="distributionDate"
                   required tabindex="2"
                   class="form-control"
                   placeholder="please select a date"
                   bsDatepicker
                   [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'MMMM D, YYYY', containerClass: 'theme-red' }"
                   (onHidden)="dateIsValid('distributionDate')"/>
          </div>
        </div>
```

[bsConfig]= that use format defined by moment.
(onHidden)= event that is executed when you out of field

you can define in some service to consume or only in your component.

```
dateIsValid(fieldName) {
if (!isNullOrUndefined(this[fieldName])) {
  if (moment(this.formatDate(this[fieldName]), 'MMMM D, YYYY', true).isValid()) {
    this[fieldName] = this.formatDate(this[fieldName]);
    this.errors[fieldName] = false;
    return true;
  } else {
    this.errors[fieldName] = true;
    return false;
  }
}
```

}